# Dynamically change size of bullet list icon according to list content using css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this unordered and ordered list in my HTML page. Mine is a CMS project and CMS team have this special requirement where they want the bullet list's icon size to increase and decrease according to the text content inside this list.

Below image is the default design of list item

[image]

But in below image, the bullet list icon's size remains same even if the text inside list have larger font-size

[image]

[image]

I tried with following code but it is not fixed

```
ul {
    li {
        position: relative;
        list-style-type: none;
        padding-left: 9/@rem;
        &::before {
            content: "\2022";
            color: @primary-c1-hex1;
            font-weight: bold;
            display: inline-block;
            width: 1em;
            margin-left: -28/@em;
            padding-right: 11/@em;
            transform: scale(0.8);
        }
        >h6, >strong  h6, > b h6 {
            display: inline-block;
        }
    }
}
```

How do I make this size dynamic using CSS? If it is not possible using only CSS. Is there a workaround using js?

Comment: please add the code which have tried. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Normally the size of these list bullets adjust to the font size (of the parent) by itself. I think your CMS editor isn't changing the li or uls font size … rather it wraps a container around its content (many editors do it like that). So this would work:

```
<ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
</ul>

<ul style="font-size: 2em;">
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
</ul>
```

… but your CMS does this:

```
<ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li><span style="font-size: 2em;">One</span></li>
    <li>Two</li>
</ul>
```

Heres a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wzugon6m/) to see this in action.

You could do something like [that](https://jsfiddle.net/tcgvjxeL/) to have better control of the circles position, color etc. but if your editor handles the text formatting like i think this wouldn't be helpful either, because it depends on the parents size and color just like the native CSS bullets do.

I would recommend to check out the syntax that your CMS editor generates.